# when import a gtlf file from blender, specular value always set to 0.5

Tags: godot

When i import a gtlf file from blender, the materials of the models always have specular value set to 0.5.

godot 4.0.1
blender 3.3

does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: I checked some Godot 3 projects which have imported models from Blender, and this is also the case for version 3. I found this issue on Github: https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter/issues/57, maybe you should ask there instead.

Comment: Also there seems some related discussion: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/69476